# How do I Convert DateTime from UTC to Local and then Capture elements reliably

Tags: javascript, datetime

I'm storing the Date/Time in SQL in UTC time zone regardless of the time zone the user is in.

Now I need to display the D/T in local time zone on the client machine - in separate fields (dropdowns for month, day, hour, etc), thus after converting the D/T to local, I need to break it apart, but using *.toLocal* and *.toLocalString* are not consistent across browsers and user preferences; I therefore can not break the string apart consistantly.

Here's what I'm doing:

```
var utcDTString=$("#utcDateTime"); // this is in format YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS coming from SQL in UTC Time zone
var utcDateObj=new Date(utcDTString+' UTC'); // create a date obj of UTC DateTime in UTC time zone
var localDT=utcDateObj.toLocaleString(); // convert the DT to local Time zone
```

Now, how do I reliably extrapolate the Year, Month, Day, Hour, Minute from *localDT* given that different browsers and user preferences could cause the string to be in various formats.

I looked to see if I could specify a layout for *.toLocaleString* but couldn't find anything.

Comment: `toLocalString` or `toLocaleString`?

Comment: 'toLocaleString' - corrected my example.

Comment: maybe you should show more your codes so that I can locate which line cause this issue. :-)

Comment: There's no more to show. `localDT` result is `3/31/2014 6:00:00 AM` on my computer but could be different based on which browser is used or which preferences I have (e.g. in Europe, they have day/month/year). I need a way to format `localDT` in a consistant way: e.g. MM/DD/YYYY HH:MM:SS AM/PM  and be 100% that will always be the format.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was making this more difficult than it needed to be. I assumed that when I used `.getHours()` that it would simply return the hours value of the current date object in its current time zone (in my case UTC). **I was wrong.**  When using `.getHours()` on a Date object that is in UTC time zone, it returns all the values in local client time - not the object's time zone. Therefore I didn't need to use `.toLocaleString` I could simply start grabbing the values from the date object and it is automatically converted to local time. Therefore this worked perfectly:

```
var sDT=$("#startMonth").data("startingvalue");
var utcdt=new Date(sDT+' UTC');
var startDateTime = utcdt;
$("#startMonth").val(startDateTime.getMonth()+1);
$("#startDay").val(startDateTime.getDate());
$("#startYear").val(startDateTime.getFullYear());
var sH=startDateTime.getHours();
if(sH>=12){
    $("#startAMPM").val("PM");
    if(sH>12){
        sH-=12;
    }
}else{
    $("#startAMPM").val("AM");
}
if(parseInt(sH)<10){
    sH="0"+sH;
}
$("#startHour").val(sH);
$("#startMinute").val(startDateTime.getMinutes());
```